# How to load a control from .xaml in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, xaml

The question is about loading some complex controls into a Stack Panel. 
I have several similar TreeListControls (from devexpress) with its own x:Name attributes I use in .cs file.

I would prefer to keep them in separate .xaml's and load while needed.

How can I load them? I havent find any working solution yet. The one I found Application.LoadComponent doesn't work properly...

For now the only way I see is to play with "Visibility" attribute, but it's total amateurism...

Answer (score 0):

You can user the [XAML reader](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ashish/archive/2007/08/14/dynamically-loading-xaml.aspx) for that purpose

Comment: It was one of the first things I found - there is no LogicalTreeHelper in Silverlight

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just create UserControls? You can instantiate them from code and add or remove them from a content control or a grid.

```
RootGrid.Children.Add(new WhateverControl());
```

Or do you need to edit the xaml at runtime?

Application.LoadComponent works for me to at least create non UI objects

```
Application.LoadComponent(Root, new Uri("/SilverlightClient;component/NavigationTreeConfig.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

And when I need to create XAML in Code I take XamlReader with a string. Didn't yet try it with files though.

```
ContentTemplate = (DataTemplate) XamlReader.Load(
                "<DataTemplate xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'><TextBlock>TemplateSelectorError: " + errorMessage + "</TextBlock></DataTemplate>");
```